# Problem when using glutStrokeString instead of glutBitmapString

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm writing my first OpenGL-program (in C using freeglut). I have the following code in my display function, that works nicely and prints out a grey colored text:

```
glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
glRasterPos2f(0, 0);
glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, (unsigned char*)"some text");
```

Now I'd like to try glutStrokeString instead of glutBitmapString. In my (humble) understanding of the API, the following should work:

```
glScalef(0.003,0.003,1);
glutStrokeString(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, (unsigned char*)"some text");
```

Running my program with this two lines instead of the glutBitmapString-call shows the text once before it disappears. Moreover from that point on all my texts displayed with glutBitmapString don't work either. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you clearing your depth buffer along with your color buffer each frame?

Comment: Yes.
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Comment: Finally solved it, it was just a missing glLoadIdentity(). Damn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved it. The problem was, that for some reason glutIdleFunc was set to my display-function and I forgot to reset my matrix (so I called glScalef again and again). It works fine now.